# Is the circle homeomorphic to a $6$ petal rose?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, circles

I am trying to explain that a circle is homeomorphic to a $6$-petal rose with the standard topology of $\mathbb R^2$, for that i'll need to explain (just in words, it is not necessary to come up with a formula) the homeomorphic function that maps one into the other.

[image: Homeomorphic Transformation.]

So starting from the center of the rose, a series of continous changes can start to push neighboring points of the rose to the border of the circle, in the end every point should be at an equal $r$ distance from the center of the rose. The same thing goes for the inverse, starting with six equidistance points in the circumference, a series of continous chanages should push the their neighboing points following the trajectory of the petals to the center of the flower. The map and the inverse should be continous because an arbitrary open ball of a certain radius in one figure, should be map to another open ball of a certain radius in the other one. The problem is in the center of the flower where the points converge, there is no simil open set in the circle, would that mean that there is no bijection relationship between their topologies?, even though they both share the same. Is the open ball at the center of the flower different from the other ones?, so despite that the and its inverse are continous, it is not homeomorphic?, or the function is not continous?. I am stuck and can't find an explanaition that makes sense, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: I think it is not homeomorphic. Because, if you remove the center point in the petals, the structure is disconnected, whereas removing no point disconnects the circle

Comment: The petal is actually homeomorphic to the wedge sum of 6 circles.

Comment: Thanks guys (vidyarthi & lisyarus), so it means that the map is not continous?

Comment: Which map? The map from the circle to the rose that you described is well-defined, and it is continuous; but it's not one-to-one -- because the six chosen points on the circle are mapped to the same center point of the rose -- so it doesn't have an inverse. And there's no other map in your post -- what you described as an attempt to go from the rose to the circle isn't completely defined, because you didn't tell us where the center goes. We can't discuss "properties" of something that hasn't been defined yet. (Although, any choice there would create a discontinuous map.)

Comment: Can I ask why you wanted to prove they are homeomorphic?

Comment: it was a question that came up at class, seems that we all fell for it XD

Answer (score 12):

They are *not* homeomorphic. If you remove the center of the rose, what remains is disconnected. However, if you remove a point from a circle, what remains stays connected.

Comment: Thanks José!, but the function is continous, meaning the reverse image of the open balls of the rose map to open balls in the circle?.

Comment: The function that you mentiond is undefined at the center of the rose, right?! Other than that, it is not hard to define, along your ideas, a homemorphism between the rose *minus its center* and the circle *minus six points*.

Answer (score 3):

Other brilliant commenters have shown that they are not homeomorphic. I wanted to add to this by showing a continuous function $f: \mathcal{S}^1 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ that maps the circle to a six-petal flower:
$$f(\theta) = (|\sin (3\theta)|, \theta)$$
Where $\theta$ specifies a point on the circle in a continuous fashion (for example, in a $\Bbb{R}^2$ setting, it could be the angle in polar coordinates). 
The function itself outputs the point in polar coordinates.

An interesting interpretation of the above is, by restricting the map on only its output on the plane (thus turning it into a surjection), that this is a quotient map.
In particular this map generates a space where six points on the circle belong to the same equivalence class while the others keep their topology intact - that is, a six-petal flower.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not true, because if you remove the center of the rose you split the rose in 6 parts (connected components) while if you remove a point from the circle you have just 1 part.